# Integration invlolving gaussian kernel

Tags: integration, mathematica, gaussian

I have been trying to solve this integration . I have tried via changing the coordinate system to cartesian coordinates system but it gets complicated. The integration is
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} r^2e^{\frac{-(r-r_0)^2}{w^2}}(cos(k_xrcos\theta)+cos(k_yrsin\theta))drd\theta$$
where $r_0,w,k_x,k_y$ are constants

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Probably involves Bessel functions.